# Issue with Rails 4.2 and Mysql2 . Cannot connect to the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, mysql2

don't know why but I cannot connect with mysql database. I am using rails v. 4.2.4 and mysql2 gem v.0.3.20. I've read about a bug with Rails 4.2 using mysql2 v.0.4 so I downgraded the gem but still cannot fix the issue. Any help, please?
Find below what I am getting from the command line:

```
MacBook-Pro-di-Sandro:ssfbase sandropalmieri$ rake db:schema:dump
rake aborted!
Mysql2::Error: Access denied for user 'ssfbase'@'localhost' to database 'ssfbase_development'
/Users/sandropalmieri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.20/lib/mysql2/client.rb:70:in `connect'
/Users/sandropalmieri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.20/lib/mysql2/client.rb:70:in `initialize'
/Users/sandropalmieri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:18:in `new'
/Users/sandropalmieri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:18:in `mysql2_connection'
/Users/sandropalmieri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:438:in `new_connection'
/Users/sandropalmieri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:448:in `checkout_new_connection'
/Users/sandropalmieri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:422:in `acquire_connection'
/Users/sandropalmieri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:349:in `block in checkout'
/Users/sandropalmieri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:348:in `checkout'
/Users/sandropalmieri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:263:in `block in connection'
/Users/sandropalmieri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:262:in `connection'
/Users/sandropalmieri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:571:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/sandropalmieri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/sandropalmieri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
/Users/sandropalmieri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:240:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/sandropalmieri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:239:in `open'
/Users/sandropalmieri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:239:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:schema:dump
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: it says access denied.

Comment: create user and pass for it. Like i did it in db.yml

Comment: I've already set user and password in my database.yml file. I can access the database from the mysql console. What you mean 'create user and pass'?